# Renaming of column names of Excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change the column name of source Excel file as shown in attached image to the format shown in Desired Excel file using **Python**. Can I get any solution here?

Source File:

[image: Source File]

Desired File:

[image: Desired File]

New to Python. Not able to find any solution online.

Comment: The [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library is pretty helpful and easy to use for reading and generating Excel files. To get more helpful responses, avoid links to images (text that people can copy and paste to work with is best), and include what you have put together so far so others can see where you're going wrong. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas: split column headers on pattern "_" finally swaplevel to move dates hierarchal index to top and reassign. List comp to rename date index and finally create a list of tuples and reassign to headers.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/your/file/Book1.xlsx")
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(pat="_", n=1, expand=True).swaplevel(0, 1)

top_level = [f"{x[:3]}-{x[3:]}" if x != "" else "" for x in df.columns.get_level_values(level=0).fillna("")]
bottom_level = list(df.columns.get_level_values(level=1))
hierarchical_columns = [(top_level[x], bottom_level[x]) for x in range(len(top_level))]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hierarchical_columns)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              Jan-10           Jan-12          Jan-14         
  Transaction    Avg 90th Pct     Avg 90th Pct    Avg 90th Pct
0     Trans-1  1.001   2.5001  3.6001   4.8001  5.001   6.3001
1     Trans-2  2.001   3.5001  4.6001   5.8001  6.001   7.3001
2     Trans-3  3.001   4.5001  5.6001   6.8001  7.001   8.3001
3     Trans-4  4.001   5.5001  6.6001   7.8001  8.001   9.3001
4     Trans-5  5.001   6.5001  7.6001   8.8001  9.001  10.3001
```